# How do I get that $|\int_a^b f| \le \int_a^b |f|$?

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a proof from my textbook that shows that $|f|$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $|\int_a^b f| \le \int_a^b |f|$, if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

> Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,b]$. Then $|f|$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and
>
> $|\int_a^b f| \le \int_a^b |f|.$
>
> Proof. Since $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, there exists $B>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le B$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Define $g:[-B,B] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(t) = |t|$. Then $g$ is continuous on $[-B,B]$ and $g \circ f = |f|$. It follows that $|f|$ is integrable.
>
> To establish the inequality between the integrals, we note that $-|f(x)| \le f(x) \le |f(x)|$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, so that
>
> $-\int_a^b |f| \le \int_a^b f \le \int_a^b |f|.$
>
> But then $|\int_a^b f| \le \int_a^b |f|$, as desired.

I wanted to know how we get that $|\int_a^b f| \le \int_a^b |f|$? Does this inequality follow from the triangle inequality?

Comment: The yellow portion has a complete proof. Which step in it is not clear to you?

Comment: $-a \leqslant x \leqslant a \iff \vert x \vert \leqslant a$.

Comment: The final step in the proof is the following: $-a \leq x \leq a$ implies $x \leq a$. To see this just consider the cases $x$ positive and $x$ negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it comes from the definition of integrability, from which:$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\cdot\Delta x_i$$where $x_i$s span whole the $[a,b]$ and by triangle inequality$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\cdot\Delta x_i\right|\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|f(x_i)\cdot\Delta x_i\right|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|f(x_i)\right|\cdot\Delta x_i$$by tending $n$ in both sides to $\infty$ we obtain$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx\right|\le\int_a^b|f(x)|dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Note $|\int_a^b f|$ equals either $\int_a^b f$ or $-\int_a^b f.$ Suppose the first case holds. Since $f\le|f|,$ we then have

$$|\int_a^b f|= \int_a^b f \le \int_a^b |f|.$$

If the second case holds, then $|\int_a^b f| = \int_a^b (-f).$ From the above, the last integral is $\le \int_a^b |-f| = \int_a^b |f|.$

Answer (score 1):

You have already proved what you need in the last $4$ rows of your question. Just notice that for $c$ not negative 
$-c \leqslant x \leqslant c \iff \vert x \vert \leqslant c$